# Using SORT command to get HASH fields from a sorted set in Redis

Tags: sorting, redis, hashmap, sortedset

For example, in `redis-cli` I've tried to create a sorted set like this:

```
zadd sortedset 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

And I've created a hash like this:

```
hset data 1 hello 
hset data 2 goodbye
hset data 3 sir
```

My goal is storing identifiers in sorted sets and get strings stored in `data` hash sorted by the sorted set ordering.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
sort sortedset by nosort get data->*
```

...which outputs:

```
1) (nil)
2) (nil)
3) (nil)
```

Actually I was expecting that `*` wildcard should be one of identifiers stored in the so-called sorted set, but it seems like it doesn't perform the substitution to each concrete identifier in the sorted set.

Am I trying to solve the issue in the right way or is there another approach to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you are right but the current implementation of the `SORT` command only accepts wildcards on the left side of the hash dereference (see `lookupKeyByPattern` in `sort.c`). That being the way it is atm, instead of `SORT`, use a Lua script to this. For example, here's a dirty quick one:

```
$ redis-cli eval "return redis.call('HMGET', KEYS[2], unpack(redis.call('ZRANGEBYSCORE', KEYS[1], '-inf', '+inf')))" 2 sortedset data
1) "hello"
2) "goodbye"
3) "sir"
```

Comment: I ended up doing it with giving paged ids given by a sorted set to `hmget` to get multiple hash keys

Comment: Well, maybe Lua is an overkill in some scenarios. In my case, I'm using C# and StackExchange.Redis, but your approach is fine!

Comment: Good solution - it has the benefit of being less RAM exhaustive at the price of multiple calls

Comment: Re. Lua overkillingness vs. SORT - I'm not sure that you'd see a major difference in performance even if the latter was implemented as you had expected it to be. SORT is arguably the most complex of Redis' commands :)

Comment: Anyway, great question - made me pull out my head out of my **s, read the source and report an issue (https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/2588) :)

Comment: hahahaha, I see, I see. Well, I said it might be an overkill in terms of maintainability. Lua is harder to debug, and since it's about executing two read operations I thought, why I would use Lua here? But anyway, both approaches are valid, why not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78398/discussion-between-itamar-haber-and-matias-fidemraizer).

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it's an use case that's not actually covered by Redis for now.

Anyway, there's an alternate approach: a combination of sorted sets and `hmget`.

If I store identifiers in a sorted set and **I get them using rank ranges with `zrange`, it's easy to get paged results from a hash using `hmget` giving multiple hash keys.**